# We show a long form & side bar for reference, Is auto-scroll good UX

Tags: scrolling

In our app user has to fill a long form(containing questions) and has to refer data from right-hand panel(also containing same questions). Users complain that need to scroll the right-hand side panel to view the relevant data is a problem. So shall we
a) Implement auto-scroll the right-hand panel, will it be weird?
b) Make the form itself short so that there is no need to scroll
Any other option ?
Is there a reference app which does this well?
Rough Wireframe below
[image]

Comment: What is the reason for displaying the related data in a separate scrolling section of the page? If users want to keep the related questions together, it appears that you can place them side by side and thus eliminate the second scroll bar problem.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like having the data on the right separate is causing the problem.

Personally I would make the relevant data on the right instead appear under the data on the left, kind of like this:

[image]

This way the relevant data is always close and both the code and the user don't have to do anything to keep them close.

If this makes the list too long, consider using multiple pages: [Single-Page vs. Multi-Page Forms: When to Use Which](https://uxmovement.com/forms/single-page-vs-multi-page-forms-when-to-use-which/)

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are well. If I were you I would also consider the UI with 2 coloumns instead of the drawer, and make it scroll with the forms together on the same page.

To be honest, it isn't simple to argue that placing the relevant data right below each forms is the right answer for your concern. Because at this point, I can't identify what type of relevant data it is. Is it just a few texts? Or a group of data points? Depending on the amount and the impact of the content to filling in each form, it might not be the only answer to put each of them to the right below of each text fields, as it can also be incredibly long.

For this concern, maybe we can also think about using hide/show accordion UI for the relevant data, so that a user can selectively decide to refers to that or not when they fill in each forms. Or, it might be also beneficial to consider granulate the steps for the form, if it's feasible to consider.